# Why are validation errors only shown on odd attempts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this view html.erb

```html
<h1>Edit</h1>

<%= render "form", appointment: @appointment, from: @source %>

<div>
  <% if params[:source] == "confirmed" %>
    <%= link_to "Volver atras", confirmed_path %>
  <% elsif params[:source] == "request" %>
    <%= link_to "Volver atras", requests_path %>
  <% elsif params[:source] == "user" %>
    <%= link_to "Volver atras", @appointment %> |
  <% end %>  
</div>
```

Form is:

```html
<%= form_with(model: appointment) do |form| %>
  <% if appointment.errors.any? %>
    <div style="color: red">
      <h2> Tu turno tiene <%= appointment.errors.count %> error/es:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% appointment.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message.split(" ")[1..].join(" ") %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :time, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.datetime_field :time%>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.hidden_field :source, value: @from %>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And my appointment controller:

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      ant= @appointment.state

      if params[:appointment][:source] == "request" 
        @appointment.state= 3

        if @appointment.update(appointment_params)
          format.html { redirect_to requests_path, notice: "Turno actualizado, espere la confirmación." }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @appointment }
        else
          @appointment.state= ant 
          format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

So when I am in the view and I choose an invalid time, I get an error that warns me, the thing is that the second time I make a mistake, I don't get the warning and the time field is reset to the one I had previously (which It doesn't happen the first time, it persists even with the error on the screen). The third time it works, but the fourth time the same happens again

I didn't know much what to do, I'm new to ruby on rails

Comment: Could you add the exact warning you get? Is this a server or client error/warning? - One thing that stands out to me is that you pass `from: @source`, but then reference `value: @from`. This should be `value: from`, without the `@`. But I don't think this is the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guest you set value of @source in edit action.

When update is failed, it renders 'edit' view and **does not execute code in edit action**

So you may want to set value for @source after form is submitted and has errors:

```
else
          @appointment.state= ant 

          # set value for @source here, ex:
          @source = params[:appointment][:source]

          format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
```